# How to check payment status with any PayPal sdk

Tags: c#, paypal

I am currently working with PayPal's Merchant SDK and I am wondering how can I check a payment status? That's especially useful for pending payment or delayed. All I keep in database is the Payer ID.

I want a method to check the payment status so that I can proceed with the payment once is it approved, or canceled, using PayPal's Merchant SDK.

Here's an example:

```
GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType req = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType
{
    Token = token
};

GetExpressCheckoutDetailsReq detailsReq = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsReq
{
    GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest = req
};

GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType response = service.GetExpressCheckoutDetails(detailsReq);
```

However in this current example I do not have the token, which is a value returned when I first create the payment, and I am not sure if I will get the payment status.

What should I do to achieve what I want? Or do I need to proceed with another SDK, or the `REST Api`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `getAck()` method per [this documentation](http://jerrythedog.com/docs/com/paypal/soap/api/AbstractResponseType.html#getAck%28%29)

It will return an AckCodeType (which can be one of the values [here](http://jerrythedog.com/docs/com/paypal/soap/api/AckCodeType.html)).  You'll want to proceed if that value is `Success` and potentially `SuccessWithWarning`.

Comment: Is it available with the Merchant SDK?

Comment: Yes according to the documentation.

Comment: jerrythedog.com is for sale at the moment i.e. the link is broken.